# docker volume не видит файлы

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Доброго времени суток!

мой `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.9"

services:
    php-fpm:
        build: php-fpm/

    nginx:
        build: nginx/
        ports: 
            - 80:80/tcp
        volumes:
            - ./conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
```

в контейнере создаётся чистая папка `conf.d` но к сожалению там нет моих файлов из папки хоста `./conf`. В чём может быть проблема почему контейнер не видит файлов в примонтированной папке?

Comment: Папка `conf`, надеюсь, не внутри `nginx/` лежит?

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov нет конечно :)

Comment: Ну тогда должно работать. Проверь, что у тебя не болтается какой-нибудь старый контейнер в списке запущенных, который не даёт новому запуститься.

Comment: ну и логи проверь сразу после старта `docker logs -f <container_id>`

Comment: Спасибо вам! Я попробовал указать полный путь и всё заработало. Еще раз огромное спасибо за внимание!